# JSON data deserialized incorrectly

Tags: c#, json, ajax

So I have a custom class:

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public BasicInfo BasicInfo { get; set; }
    public EmployeesInfo EmployeesInfo { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In my view, I want to send data back to my controller function:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveCompanyInfoWithOutBalanceSheet(CompanyInfo model)
 {
    ...
 }
```

The Ajax function is like this:

```
function onSubmit(){
    basicInfoFormData = $("#basicInfoForm").serialize();
    employeesInfoFormData = $("#employeesInfoForm").serialize();
    var companyInfoData = 
    {
      basicInfoFormData, employeesInfoFormData
    };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveCompanyInfoWithOutBalanceSheet")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(companyInfoData),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success)
                    secondStepOnSubmit();
                else
                    submitError();
            }
        });
}
```

When I run the ajax function, my controller function do successfully receive the HTTP request and translate it to my custom class "`CompanyInfo`". However, there's one issue here. The last property `cof` my "`BasicInfo`" class is a `string`, the name of the property is "`Website`". If I set a breakpoint in the controller method, I can see that the binder doesn't deserialize the "`Website`" property correctly. Below is the value that Binder assigned to the "`Website`" property:

```
"test_email_address \",\"employeesInfoFormData\":\"EmployeesInfo.ID=0"
```

"`test_email_address`" is what I typed in for "`WebSite`" but somehow the binder includes the beginning of the "`EmployeesInfo`" part of the **JSON** `string` as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the specify `contentType: "application/json"` in your request object, jQuery x-form-url-encodes the body by default.

Comment: Did it worked as per the above comment "contentType: "application/json"" ?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Hey, I tried adding contentType:"application/json" but it didn't work, actually now the model is null in my controller function

Comment: Exactly, when you want your C# Method (EditAssetOnboarding) need parameter as a model then you should pass the whole model with data - not few attribute values of the model

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am confused here, so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want your C# Action(`SaveCompanyInfoWithOutBalanceSheet`) need parameter as a model(`CompanyInfo`) then you should pass the whole model with data - not few `attribute` values of the model.

For Example, if your `Model` is having three `properties` like below

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public BasicInfo BasicInfo { get; set; }
    public EmployeesInfo EmployeesInfo { get; set; }       
}
```

And your `Controller` `Action` is like below

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveCompanyInfoWithOutBalanceSheet(CompanyInfo companyInfo)
 {
    ...
 }
```

So, in javascript function you need to get the values where you have assigned to your html controls. **Generate the correct structure of your model and pass it as parameter.**

In your model, it holds one `int` attribute and two separate `classes` as two other `attributes`. So, when you are sending the parameter create the proper structure and pass it. It should work

```
function onSubmit(){
    var companyIdValue =  $("#yourcompanyidtextbox").val();
    //Ensure the basicInfoFormData contains all the property values of BasicInfo class
    var basicInfoFormData = $("#basicInfoForm").serialize();
    //Ensure the employeesInfoFormData contains all the property values of EmployeesInfo class
    var employeesInfoFormData = $("#employeesInfoForm").serialize();
    var companyInfo = 
    {
      CompanyID : companyIdValue,
      BasicInfo : basicInfoFormData, 
      EmployeesInfo : employeesInfoFormData
    };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveCompanyInfoWithOutBalanceSheet")',               
            data: JSON.stringify(companyInfo),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success)
                    secondStepOnSubmit();
                else
                    submitError();
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {                    
               alert("Status: " + textStatus + "Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
```

Hope you are clear.